# How to highlight two same/different values in two columns in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google sheets, I have a table of the costs of the products for the first and second quarters of the year.

```
Q1 cost|Q2 cost
80.    |80
65.    |70
55.    |60
95.    |95
```

I want to compare the costs and color the costs that stayed the same in green and the ones that changed in red. Do you know how can I do it in google sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is somewhat similar on what @player0 provided. I just added some additional condition for better results.

### You can use [custom formulas with conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Cexample%2Cuse-custom-formulas-with-conditional-formatting) in Google sheets with the following Conditional format rules:

- Apply to range: `A2:B`

> Assuming your header Q1 cost and Q2 cost is in row 1

- Custom Formula for Green: `=AND(LEN($A2),$A2=$B2)`
- Custom Formula for Red: `=AND(LEN($A2),$A2<>$B2)`

> I added additional condition LEN($A2) to check if cell is not empty so that it will not highlight empty cells in column A and B with green.

### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

apply on range A2:B for green:

```
=($A2=$B2)*$A2<>""
```

and for red:

```
=($A2<>$B2)*$A2<>""
```